# What is the difference in meaning between the following sentences?

Tags: sentence-construction, punctuation, commas

1. The author ended his story by saying "life is short."
2. The author ended his story saying "life is short."

Does there need to be a comma after "story" in the second sentence? If so, why?

Comment: There is no real difference in meaning between these sentences, and yes, a comma is expected after "story" in the second sentence, as a convenient way to break up the two actions.